# Showing only a portion of the original image in a UIImageView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimageview

How can i show only a portion of the original image in a UIImageView

This question may be very familiar and old, But the reason for asking again is,i could not find a workable idea with the help of those answers
Many said set image.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;   (but not working)

I need almost a rectangle containing the center of the original image,How do I get this ?

**I do make this working,when i am displaying a static image to my app and setting Content mode of UIImageVie as Aspect Fill.
But this is not workable in the case when i am displaying an image from url and using NSData**

Adding my code and the images

```
   NSString *weburl = @"http://topnews.in/files/Sachin-Tendulkar_15.jpg";
   UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 50, 108, 86)];
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:weburl];
   NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
   imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

   [self.view addSubview:imageView];
```

[image: Original Image]
[image: Current outPut]
[image: need]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you added the UIImageView form XIB, you can find a "mode" property there and then you can see and set different modes from there (from Interface builder). Or by programatically, you can set different modes by

```
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Comment: atleast please read the question..That is not about setting content mode

Comment: try now. Write down your comment

Comment: now u came with a bang.....Thanks buddy, Thank u so much
Now u deserve +1....and the accept

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
self.imageView.layer.contentsRect = CGRectMake(0.25, 0.25, 0.5, 0.5);
```

self.imageView will display middle part of image. You can calculate itself the required values of CGRect ​

Comment: I came across this and was wondering, can I show a part of the image, then when I resize the imageview, show the whole image?

Comment: Thank you, this is so much easier than cropping an image. Swift 4 code: `self.backgroundImageView.layer.contentsRect = CGRect(x: 0.25, y: 0.25, width: 0.5, height: 0.5)`

Answer (score 3):

For this kind of output, you need to crop the image according to your requirement.

Cropping code as below which can be used.

```
-(UIImage *) CropImageFromTop:(UIImage *)image
{
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([image CGImage], CGRectMake(0, 12, image.size.width, image.size.height - 12));
    UIImage *cropimage = [[[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:imageRef] autorelease];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    return cropimage;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you try to scale image and then add image in UiImageView and set center that image then it is in center. code of scale image is

```
-(UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage *)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize{
   UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
   [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
   UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
   UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
   return newImage;
```

}

then you set the center of that image and add in the image view i hope this is work