# Masking overlapping PNGs with each other in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, png, mask

I have a collection of UIImageViews, made from PNGs with transparency.

I want to be able to overlap these images on top of each other, but only show where they overlap, not the entire image. So image B is placed over image A, but I only want to display image B where image A is not transparent.

The UIImageViews also move around.

So effectively I want to use one PNG to mask another PNG, using Objective C.

Can this be done?

Comment: Why has this been marked as off topic? This is definitely about programming, I want to know if and how I can mask these PNGs with Objective C programatically. Can anybody explain to me why someone would consider that "This question does not appear to be about programming,"??

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the ideal way to accomplish this, but you could do this by using a combination of masking and cropping.

So, for example, you check to see if Image A is transparent, if it is, perform some masking on the two images. [Masking Tutorial Here](http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/how-to-mask-an-image.html#comment-47347)

After you've masked the images, perform a cropping operation based on the intersecting coordinates. [Check the Second Answer Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13578151/showing-only-a-portion-of-the-original-image-in-a-uiimageview)

In the event that that Image A is not transparent, just perform the cropping operation without masking the object. Not sure if this will help, but I figure it will give you a start!